# Gulp globbing to move files creates extra folders?

Tags: gulp, glob

I have a gulp task to move fonts:

```
gulp.task('move', function(cb) {
  return gulp.src('./packages/my-package@1.0.17-alpha.3/fonts/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/fonts/'));
});
```

This working however the my-package number will change. Im trying to alter the gulp task so that it will still work when the package number changes:

```
gulp.task('move', function(cb) {
  return gulp.src('./packages/my-package@*/fonts/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/fonts/'));
});
```

This does move the fonts but it also adds some folders.

This is what it does:

```
./build/fonts/my-package@1.0.17-alpha.3/fonts/ (fonts here)
```

What I need is this:

```
./build/fonts/ (fonts here)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive fixed this with gulp-flatten:

```
var flatten = require('gulp-flatten');

gulp.task('move', function(cb) {
  return gulp.src('./packages/my-package@1.0.17-alpha.3/fonts/*')
    .pipe(flatten())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/fonts/'));
});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten